# Standard symplectic form on a sphere is an area form in cylindrical coordinates.

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Consider a symplectic form $\omega_x(\xi,\nu)=\langle x,\xi\times \nu\rangle$ on $S^2$ where $x\in S^2$ and $\xi,\nu\in T_x S^2$ and a parametrization $\phi:U\to S^2$ where $U=(0,2\pi)\times(-1,1)$ and $\phi(\theta,x_3)=(\sqrt{1-x_3^2}\cos(\theta),\sqrt{1-x_3^2}\sin(\theta),x_3)$.

I want to show that $\phi^*\omega_x=\omega_{st}$ where $\omega_{st}=d\theta\wedge dx_3$. My logic is the following:

It's enough to show that $\phi^*\omega_x(v,w)=\omega_{st}(v,w)$ for all $v,w\in T_{p}U$ where $\phi(p)=x$. However, since $T_pU$ is spanned by two vectors $\partial_{\theta}$ and $\partial_{x_3}$, then it's enough to show that
$$\phi^*\omega_x(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{x_3})=\omega_{st}(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{x_3})=1$$
where $\phi^*\omega_x(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{x_3})=\omega_x(d\phi_p(\partial_{\theta}),d\phi_p(\partial_{x_3})).$
By direct computation i.e. finding $d\phi_p$ and computing $\omega_x(d\phi_p(\partial_{\theta}),d\phi_p(\partial_{x_3}))$ explicitly by using a definition, we can check that $\phi^*\omega_x(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{x_3})=1$.

Therefore, $\phi^*\omega_x=\omega_{st}$ as they agree on the basis vectors.

*I just want to check if this proof makes sense.* Thank you!

Comment: This is a bit too much abuse of notation for me. When you have a *chart* $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$, it's standard to use $\partial/\partial x^j$ for the basis vectors for the tangent space. But here, it's better to write $\partial\phi/\partial\theta$ and $\partial\phi/\partial x_3$ for the tangent vectors to the sphere, so as not to confuse the tangent vectors in the two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct (assuming that you are checking $\phi^*\omega_x(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{x_3})=\omega_{st}(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{x_3})$ for **all** $p$). Note that the above argument works for any top form (not only for surfaces), since $\wedge^n \mathbb (R^n)^*$ is one dimensional, then two top forms $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \wedge ^n\mathbb R^n $ are the same if and only if
$$ \omega_1 (e_1, \cdots, e_n ) = \omega_2(e_1, \cdots, e_n)$$
for any fixed basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you! Also, isn't that true that if two $k$-forms $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\Omega^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ agree on a fixed basis, then they are the same? I use that fact that any $k$-form $\omega$ can be written as $\omega=\sum_I a_I dx_I$ where $I$ is an ordered indexing for $k$ choose $n$ covectors $dx_i$ i.e. for some given $I$, $dx_I=dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_k$ for example.

Comment: Yes that's also true, but in that case you will need to check all the possible combinations, instead of just one when $k=n$. @eightc